# Error installing Google AppEngine plugin in Eclipse Juno (4.2)

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

When I try to install the eclipse plugin for GAE I get an error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google App Engine Java SDK 1.6.4 1.6.4.v201203300216r37 (com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group 1.6.4.v201203300216r37)

I'm using the http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 update URL, which is the latest I could find. Has anyone solved this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this :  http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 as an update site

Source: http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=71#makechanges

Comment: still, i m getting an error.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.css.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was forgetting to start eclipse as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is that we don't yet support 4.2, answer is to have patience. Eclipse plugins are complex beasts, and 4.2 is fairly new.

Comment: Can you give any indication of expected timeframe for a 4.2 release?  Are beta versions available for testing?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith - 4.2 still appears to be broken - see [the trouble I've been having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187595/is-the-google-eclipse-plugin-for-juno-eclipse-4-2-broken)

Answer (score 2):

See this post which explains how to work around this: 
https://plus.google.com/110140945975184013033/posts/ePFpQZYhPQq

```
How to Install GWT Plugin for Eclipse on 3.8 or Juno:

1. Download zipped update site for 3.7 
   from http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html
2. Unzip content.jar; rm content.jar
3. Edit content.xml; change 
   <required namespace='org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu' 
       name='org.eclipse.platform.feature.group' range='[3.7.0,3.8.0)'/> 
   to 
   <required namespace='org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu' 
       name='org.eclipse.platform.feature.group' range='3.7.0'/>
4. jar cMf content.jar content.xml (zip won't work)
5. Install from local update site
```

Please note that some features of the plugin might not work as they should (for example when running in debugging mode my Eclipse Juno crashed a couple of times).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the antivirus (for some unknown reason) blocks the reading of xml file. Solution: PAUSE PROTECTION during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an issue like this when I am try to install plug in [link to plugin](https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2) in eclipse 4.2.2

Error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2   -rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.1.v201303211244-rel-r42)
>     Missing requirement: Google Suite Plugin 3.2.1.v201303211244-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.ext 3.2.1.v201303211244-rel-r42) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.1.v201303211244-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.1.v201303211244-rel-r42)
>       To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.ext [3.2.1.v201303211244-rel-r42]

I fixed this issue by click **Help -> Check for updates**, after that I installed this plug in and work as expected.