# Is the Google Eclipse Plugin for Juno (Eclipse 4.2) broken?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno, google-eclipse-plugin

I just installed Eclipse EE Juno (4.2) and a whole slew of plugins for it. I am now attempting to install the Google plugin (GAE and GWT) and am getting an error when adding the update site through Juno's `Install new software` window:

```
Name: Google-Plugin
Location: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
```

When I try to enter this I get:

> Could not find http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152818/error-installing-google-appengine-plugin-in-eclipse-juno-4-2) question from a few months ago. Although I am having a very similar problem, I think I have a different problem altogether.

When I change the `Location` to `http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7`, I get the same error (except with `3.7` appended on the end of the error message instead of `4.2`). I definitely have Internet access (how else would I be posting this question?!) so that's not the issue. If this was only working for the 4.2 plugin, I would happily try the "workaround" mentioned in the other post, or even step back down to Eclipse 3.7 (I **have** to have this plugin!) until 4.2 was working. But the fact that it's not even working for 3.7 tells me that something else is awrye here. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

Just to mess around with things, I have downloaded Indigo (3.7) and immediately attempted to install the Google-Eclipse plugin.  I entered the following for my update site:

> http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7

And received a nasty error:

```
Artifact not found: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/compositeContent.xml.
Artifact not found: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/compositeContent.xml.
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/compositeContent.xml
```

Am I going *crazy* here?!?! I've installed my fair share of Eclipse plugins and *never* had this much trouble. Especially from Google. And I know its not my Internet connection or my Eclipse instance because *before* I attempted to install the Google plugin, I installed Subversive, IvyDE and EclEmma...

Comment: A little too late but in my case, the corporate web filter was blocking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was also broken for me a little while ago, but seems to be working now.  Maybe the site was down for a bit?

Comment: Thanks @X24 - I just made an edit - link seems to be broken for 3.7 as well - any thoughts? I'm losing my mind here!

Comment: @4herpsand7derpsago: I've literally just installed it successfully (using dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2).  I'd suggest giving it another try.

Comment: Yep - worked that time (about 10th try)... I can't wait to start developing for GAE, I'm now *extremely* confident in their 99.95% SLA uptime! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the plugin from archive as described in the link:
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip

Basically what you are doing is, you download the plugin as a zip(archive) and browse this archive instead of update site, during the plugin installation.