# Google Plugin for Eclipse installation error

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse and the Google Plugin to begin compiling the Google Web Toolkit from the source and building a sample application with it. However, upon installation of the plugin, I am getting this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaqEW.png

From the look of the error, I'd say this might have something to do with Google actually, unless I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 
Help-> Install New Software -> paht: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

did you try same link?

Comment: Yep, that did it. I must have been trying to install the wrong version. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Eclipse as Administrator? Some of the software sources are finicky if you don't. I know I had a similar problem installing the Android Tools SDK.

I've also found [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152818/error-installing-google-appengine-plugin-in-eclipse-juno-4-2), if it helps.